# Agregar varias consultas (rows) en un Gridview ASP y SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp, gridview

[![0

tengo una tabla con una lista enorme de materiales, necesito seleccionar varios materiales para posteriormente generar un PDF con dichos materiales, estoy trabado en esa parte puesto que no se como ir agregando varios materiales sin que se borre el primero, es decir, el usuario hará aprox 5-10 SELECT pero ahora mismo solo puedo mostrar 1 en el gridview][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ44H.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ44H.png)

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de haber entendido tu problema. En el ejemplo que te muestro a continuación cada vez que pulsas en  botón de añadir material, lo añadirá al contenido previo del GridView. En la variable _source de tipo BindingSource estará contenida la lista de materiales añadidos.

Por favor déjame saber si te ayudé. Suerte

```
public partial class frmtest : Form
{
    private List<Materiales> _materiales = new List<Materiales>();
    private BindingSource _source;

    private int index = 0;

    public frmtest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmtest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        _source = new BindingSource();

        _source.DataSource = new List<Materiales>();

        MyDataGridView.DataSource = _source;
    }

    private void cmdAddMaterial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index++;

        _source.Add(new Materiales()
        {
            id = index,
            desc = "material nº " + index.ToString()
        });
    }
}





        protected void btnBuscarMat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombre.Text))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, 
          this.Page.GetType(),
                  "err_msg",
                  "alert('Ingrese # de Material');",
                  true);
    }
    else
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
         parte,descripcion,ublinea,ubalmacen,cantcajas,plataforma,parada 
         from pfp_ayudas_viajeras where reg like '" + txtNombre.Text + "%'", cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        this.GridView1.DataSource = (dt);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adjunté una imagen. pero al parecer no la agregué bien, aparece al final de la pregunta como un "1", de igual manera adjunto el código con el que mando llamar una consulta al gridview

Comment: Sí llegué a ver las imágenes. ¿Pudo resolver el problema? Saludos

Comment: Sigo con el problema Inge :/

Comment: Pon el código, a ver si podemos hacer algo al respecto

Comment: Ya lo puse inge, debajo del codigo que me escribiste, puse el mio, logras verlo? lo siento, es que soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Hola. Yo sí he podido verlo. Le echaré un vistazo y te diré si veo algo. Lo suyo sería que edites tu pregunta, y en ella incluyas el código para que también otros miembros de la comunidad puedan participar. Hazlo si tienes ocasión por favor. Seguimos hablando